# How to use for loop to fill inner html with multiple array data?

Tags: typescript

i have 4 data arrays that i want to put in to for loop to fill inner html of an element or to generate that same elements with different iteration data from array.

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = (driverPosition + " " + nameLastName + " " + driverSponsor + " " + driverPoints);

in the loop which works but it only returns the last value and i want it to return all values one below the other.

```
    let driverPositionArray = [];
    let nameLastNameDriver = [];
    let listaSponsora = [];
    let driverPointsArray = [];
    let i = 0;

 for (; i < duzinaNumber; i++) {
      nameVozaca = response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings[i].Driver.givenName;
      prezimeVozaca = response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings[i].Driver.driverId;
      // console.log("name + last name"+ " " + nameVozaca + " " + prezimeVozaca);
      driverPosition = (response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings[i].position);
      // console.log("this is the position of the current driver " + driverPosition);
      driverPoints = response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings[i].points;
      // console.log("current driver points " + driverPoints);
      // console.log("this is iteration number" +" "+ i);

      driverSponsor = response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings[i].Constructors[0].name;
      //  console.log(driverSponsor); radi ok
      //   console.log( "position " + driverPosition +  " ime Vozaca " + nameVozaca + " prezime Vozaca " + prezimeVozaca + " " + " Points " + driverPoints);

      driverPositionArray.push(driverPosition);
      nameLastName = (nameVozaca + " " + prezimeVozaca);  // vraca string imena i prezimena u array listu
      nameLastNameDriver.push(nameLastName);
      listaSponsora.push(driverSponsor);
      driverPointsArray.push(driverPoints);
      //console.log(nameLastName);
      //  imenaVozaca.push(nameVozaca);
    }
```

}

i want to have a for loop that takes the data from the 4 arrays and fills them in the html in a p tag.[image]

Comment: Just to clarify since I'm not sure your intent is translating clearly. You want to `concat` the arrays to combine them, and then render all their values as a string into one `<p>` tag? Or a new `<p>` tag for each item? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I want to merge the arrays then for every iteration of the array i want to make a new p element with the current data.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML +=   "" + driverPosition + "" + nameLastName + "" + driverSponsor + "" + driverPoints + "
";

Comment: put it inside the loop it fills the data to a table that is made